# Bitbucket Pipelines Push full files to ftp

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

We are currently testing Bitbucket pipelines Beta (love it so far).
However I have a question.
We are uploading our source/ files fine using git-ftp , but on top of that we need to push the full Subdomain patch files (Index.php & .htaccess) they dont very often change, but we have to push them each time fully and not just the changes. 
So far we can't get it working using git-ftp.
Are we doing something wrong?

The error message we keep keeping is:

> - git ftp push --user $Username --passwd $Pwd ftp://dev.iwantaspeaker.com/public_html/
>     No changed files for dev.iwantaspeaker.com/public_html/. Everything up-to-date.

I have included some of the code below and hope you can help. Thanks.

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "Pipeline Init for dev."
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - echo "'_$(git status -uno --porcelain | wc -l)_'"
            - git status -uno --porcelain
            - echo "Initiating Push site:dev Source."
            - git config git-ftp.syncroot Source/
            - git ftp push --user $Username --passwd $Pwd ftp://dev.iwantaspeaker.com/public_html/
            - echo "Initiating Push site:dev subDomianPatch."
            - git config git-ftp.syncroot SubDomainPatches/dev/dev_subdomain_patch/public_html/
            - git ftp push --user $Username --passwd $Pwd ftp://dev.iwantaspeaker.com/public_html/
```

Comment: have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use file .git-ftp-include**

https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#syncing-untracked-files